# Angular printjs: ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, printjs

I'm trying to use `printJS` in Angular and print an image (PNG). I did the import:

```
    import { printJS } from "print-js/dist/print.min.js";
```

Then I execute this printing code in function, according to the [documentation](http://printjs.crabbly.com/#documentation):

```
    printJS('no-image.png', 'image');
```

I got following error:
[image]

I can't find solution to fix this.

Comment: Try to import the non minified version of the script

Comment: @bambam I changed import to `import { printJS } from "print-js/dist/print.js";` it compiles without any errors but the problem is the same.

Comment: Ah it's a node_module.. dfsq's answer should solve it then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to use default import for this library:

```
import printJS from "print-js";
```

Also, for NPM packages you should never import directly from js path. Usually you would just import from package itself, in your case `print-js`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it works nice! And thanks for the advice I will keep that in my mind :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `npm i print-js --save`
2. `import * as printJS from 'print-js';`

It works for me in the project using Angular 12